# Regex that matches string before comma unless the text contains a clasped list that is also separated by comma

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say this is my text:

```
"a, b, c (1, 2, 3), d, f (x, y)"
```

I want to match every point of the enumeration but I also don't want the sub list comma interpreted as a terminating character. I want a regex to extract the following matches:

```
a
b
c (1,2,3)
d
f (x, y)
```

I tried using an optional lookahead but I simply can't get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `string.split` function.

```
> "a, b, c (1, 2, 3), d, f (x, y)".split(/,\s*(?![^()]*\))/)
=> ["a", "b", "c (1, 2, 3)", "d", "f (x, y)"]
```

The above regex would match all the commas and the following zero or more spaces only if it's not followed by (*`[^()]*` any char but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times and a closing brace `)`*)